# How I can count the value of a coulmn of different group?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose there are 5 different columns in my data set.

```
Group   person   driving-license   #-cars   #trips
  1       1             (1)yes       2        1
  1       1             (1)yes       2        2
  1       1             (1)yes       2        3
  1       2             (1)yes       2        1
  1       2             (1)yes       2        2    
  2       1             (0)No        1        1
  2       1             (0)No        1        2
  2       2             (1)yes       1        1
  2       2             (1)yes       1        2
  2       2             (1)yes       1        3
```

in this sample there are 2 groups and in the first group there are 2 persons .The first one has 3 trips and second person 2 trips. So the 3 first rows belongs to the first person and next 2 rows to second person.

4-th columns is the number of cars in each groups. in first group there are 2 cars and in second group 1.

I want to create a vector and check that if in each groups the number of persons with driving-license is more than cars or not. (1 if it is and 0 otherwise).

What is the shortest and best way to do that?

Comment: Can you clarify "number of persons with driving-license is more than cars or not."?

Comment: @heds1 for example in first group 2 persons have D-L and there is 2 cars so my new vector is 0. in second group also same situation 1 person has D-L and there is 1 car.

Comment: @heds1  I meant in each group if #cars is less than PP with D_L or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can compare number of `persons` in each `Group` to the number of `cars`.

---

**Comparing number of persons with driving license to the number of cars in each group:**

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter(DrivingLicense=="(1)yes") %>% 
  mutate(MyVector=+(n_distinct(person)>cars)) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(MyVector=max(MyVector)) %>% 
  left_join(df1, ., by="Group")
#>    Group person DrivingLicense cars trips MyVector
#> 1      1      1         (1)yes    2     1        0
#> 2      1      1         (1)yes    2     2        0
#> 3      1      1         (1)yes    2     3        0
#> 4      1      2         (1)yes    2     1        0
#> 5      1      2         (1)yes    2     2        0
#> 6      2      1          (0)No    1     1        1
#> 7      2      1          (0)No    1     2        1
#> 8      2      2         (1)yes    1     1        1
#> 9      2      2         (1)yes    1     2        1
#> 10     2      2         (1)yes    1     3        1
```

---

**Based on all persons regardless of their driving status:**

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(MyVector=+(n_distinct(person)>cars))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   Group [2]
#>    Group person DrivingLicense  cars trips MyVector
#>    <int>  <int> <fct>          <int> <int>    <int>
#>  1     1      1 (1)yes             2     1        0
#>  2     1      1 (1)yes             2     2        0
#>  3     1      1 (1)yes             2     3        0
#>  4     1      2 (1)yes             2     1        0
#>  5     1      2 (1)yes             2     2        0
#>  6     2      1 (0)No              1     1        1
#>  7     2      1 (0)No              1     2        1
#>  8     2      2 (1)yes             1     1        1
#>  9     2      2 (1)yes             1     2        1
#> 10     2      2 (1)yes             1     3        1
```

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="Group   person   DrivingLicense   cars   trips
  1       1             (1)yes       2        1
  1       1             (1)yes       2        2
  1       1             (1)yes       2        3
  1       2             (1)yes       2        1
  1       2             (1)yes       2        2    
  2       1             (0)No        1        1
  2       1             (0)No        1        2
  2       2             (1)yes       1        1
  2       2             (1)yes       1        2
  2       2             (1)yes       1        3", header=T)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I removed rows with NO then used your first answer . it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question, you want to count the number of `people` in each `Group` that has a License, compare to the number of cars in that `Group` and decide if the number of people (`person`) is greater or not.

This can be achieved with `data.table`, which is a very fast package, see `?data.table`:

```
dt[`driving-license` %like% "yes", 
   .(peopleWithLicense = uniqueN(person), cars = mean(`#-cars`)), 
   by = Group][, 
               .(Group, peopleWithLicense, 
                 cars, 
                 morePeopleThanCars = peopleWithLicense > cars)][]
```

### What is in there:

`dt[`driving-license`%like% "yes"` filters only the rows for which the person has a license.

`.(peopleWithLicense = uniqueN(person), cars = mean('#-cars'))` calculates the number of unique values in variable `person`, giving the name `peopleWithLicense` to the result, and calculates the average of cars `by = Group`, which is pretty self-explanatory.

`][` is a "chained command", that is, we pass the result of the first data.table (the filtered, grouped calculation of people and cars) to a new set of operations:

`.(Group, peopleWithLicense, cars,` simply print the values of those variables, while
`morePeopleThanCars = peopleWithLicense > cars` checks if there are more people than cars, and assigns that [logical value] to a variable.
The final `[]` prints the result to the screen.

### The output is

```
   Group peopleWithLicense cars morePeopleThanCars
1:     1                 2    2              FALSE
2:     2                 1    1              FALSE
```

If you want the `0 / 1` values instead `FALSE / TRUE`, then just replace the last line with `morePeopleThanCars = 1L * (peopleWithLicense > cars))][]`

### The data I used:

```
dt <- fread("Group   person   driving-license   #-cars   #trips
   1       1             (1)yes       2        1
   1       1             (1)yes       2        2
   1       1             (1)yes       2        3
   1       2             (1)yes       2        1
   1       2             (1)yes       2        2    
   2       1             (0)No        1        1
   2       1             (0)No        1        2
   2       2             (1)yes       1        1
   2       2             (1)yes       1        2
   2       2             (1)yes       1        3")
```